# Is possible use the same route to many controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a unique route for various controllers to simplify the URL. I want to define a order of priority for the controllers, like this:

**RouteConfig:**

```
routes.MapRoute("Category", "{*url}", new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Product", "{*url}", new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("User", "{*url}", new { controller = "User", action = "Index" });
```

**CategoryController:**

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string url)
    {
        var categoryManager = new CategoryManager();
        var category = categoryManager.GetByURL(url);

        if (category != null)
        {
            return View(category); 
        }

        // ignore and try next controller
    }
}
```

**ProductController:**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string url)
    {
        var productManager = new ProductManager();
        var product= productManager.GetByURL(url);

        if (product!= null)
        {
            return View(product); 
        }

        // ignore and try next controller
    }
}
```

**UserController:**

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string url)
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager();
        var user = userManager.GetByURL(url);

        if (user != null)
        {
            return View(user); 
        }

        // ignore and try next controller
    }
}
```

**Examples:**

When the URL is **/computers**:

- *CategoryController* find the *category* entity and return the correct view;

When the URL is **/iphone5**:

- *CategoryController* don´t find the *category* and ignores;
- *ProductController* find the *product* entity and return the correct view;

When the URL is **/charles**:

- *CategoryController* don´t find the *category* and ignores;
- *ProductController* don´t find the *product* and ignores;
- *UserController* find the user *entity* and return the correct view;

I don´t know how to do that, someone can help me?

I´m crazy doing this?

Note: I want one Controller for each for better organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, but perhaps not very efficient and robust way, is to route to a generic action in a controller where you determine the actual action. It would look something like this:

```
public class CommonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GenericUrl(string url)
    {
        if (url is a category)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Category", new { categoryId = id });
        }

        if (url is a product)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Product", new { productId = id });
        }

        if (url is a user)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { userId = id });
        }

        return HttpNotFound();  // Might also be the homepage for example.
    }
}
```

You just have to define one route:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "{*url}", new { controller = "Common", action = "GenericUrl"});
```

It's also an option to maintain a 'slug' table in your database where you can lookup slugs and retrieve their associated entity type, unique id and controller/action. [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/) has a implementation of this  using a custom route type.

Comment: I think that the simple way is the best way... always. You got the point! The "slug" table will reduce a lot the calls to database, and is a good way to keep the unique URIs. I will change my entities. Thank you for the ideia.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that functionality is not built right into the base routing libraries.

You would need to create a new custom Route class that inherits RouteBase and returns `null` from the GetRouteData override when you fail to get a hit.  Returning null would allow fallback down to the next route handler.

Example:

```
public class CategoryRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (we dont find our category)
            return null;
        else
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Category");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
            routeData.Values.Add("url", catUrl);

            return routeData;
        }
    }
}
```

Then instead of calling MapRoute, simply call Add, as follows:

```
routes.Add("CategoryRoute", new CategoryRoute());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried and this works but the performance is very slow, the call for database on the route class can not be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, this doesn't make a lot of sense.  But you could create one controller and the partial it based on your structure into different files and then have one Index method that goes down the line and then returns the correct view.

```
// Category.cs
public partial MainController :  

// Product.cs
public partial MainController :

// User.cs
public parital MainController :
```

MainController.cs would have an Index method that could call a method from each of the files depending on the URL

```
public ActionResult Index(string url){
   // Logic for determining which method to call in the specific file here
}
```

This allows you to have organizational boundaries by having separate files but only one controller.  But I don't think I would recommend it.

Comment: I thought on this, but seems very crazy. I don't think I would recommend it too.

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Essentially, you can create route constraints, which are rules that specify if a route should be executed or not. You used to set these in your routes, but they've recently changed to attributes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "ProductPage",
url: "{productId}/{productTitle}",
defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Show" },
constraints: new { productId = "\\d+" }
);
```

Attributes:

```
[Route("{productId:int}/{productTitle}")]
public ActionResult Show(int productId) { ... }
```

Of course, this isn't the only way to write a constraint. Each version of MVC has had this ability. A word of caution, be careful when using these that you don't inadvertently introduce performance issues by writing functions that query the db. If you need that (for instance, to test if an object exists before capturing the route) then cache the values.

Good luck!

Comment: This way needs a prefix for the URIs.

Comment: Did you even read the link I sent? It explains route constraints and gives examples. I guess putting in effort wasn't what you were looking for. Enjoy your hack solution.